# Closed subset of the real line without isolated points.

Tags: general-topology

Let $F$ a closed subset of the real line without isolated points.

Can we deduce that $F$ is a union of closed intervals of $\mathbb{R}$?

EDIT : As @Arthur said, of course closed intervals with positive length. Thank you for your comment, it is not really easy otherwise ^^.

Comment: Does a single point count as a closed interval (like $\{0\} = [0,0]$)? Because if so, then _any_ subset of the real line is a union of closed intervals, and this problem becomes somewhat boring. So if I were to guess, I would say that you want to ask about unions of closed intervals _with positive length_.

Comment: Either "Yes, because of what @Arthur said" or "No because Cantor set".

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Does it matter? Non-disjoint intervals can be merged into single intervals, and you can reduce a non-disjoint union to a disjoint one, can you not? Are there infinity-related subtleties that I'm missing? Or are you just saying "disjoint" to get a _unique_ representation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define "closed interval". Typically the definition goes like this: for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

$$[a,b]:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\ |\ a\leq x\leq b\}$$

and therefore singletons $\{c\}$ are closed intervals as well, i.e. $[c,c]=\{c\}$. Thus **any** subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a union of closed intervals. Even disjoint union.

However if by "closed interval" you mean "closed interval of non-zero length" (equivalently "closed intervals which are not singletons") then the answer is "no" because [the Cantor set has no isolated points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42580/show-that-the-cantor-set-contains-no-isolated-points). And the Cantor set does not contain any open interval (and thus closed of non-zero length as well) because it is totally disconnected.